# How can I upload an image from my ios app to my bucket stored on aws s3 and do all of that in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There are lots and lots examples of that written in obj C, but I'm looking for a `Swift` solution. So far all I could find is this one https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Swift but it's not that clear for me.

I already configured the `s3` on aws webpage, I also created and filled file `Constans.swift`:

```
import AWSS3
import Foundation

let CognitoRegionType = AWSRegionType.XXXXX  
let DefaultServiceRegionType = AWSRegionType.XXXXX 
let CognitoIdentityPoolId = "MyCognitoIdentityPoolId"
let S3BucketName = "MyS3BucketName"
```

I also added the following lines to `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoRegionType, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

I also have a class in Swift with a button and an image view controller and so far when I click the button I can take the photo from gallery or camera and it shows on the image view. This is my code responsible for that:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func captureImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imageFromSource = UIImagePickerController()
    imageFromSource.delegate = self
    imageFromSource.allowsEditing = false

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){

        imageFromSource.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera

    }
    else{

        imageFromSource.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

    }

    self.presentViewController(imageFromSource, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    imageView.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})

}
```

Now all I want is to add a new button that will be responsible for uploading this photo to my s3 bucket, something like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZ54fH8AFUk (unfortunately it's in objective c here, I would be so grateful if you could help me with a swift version...). Thanks!

====EDIT

I've been following a tutorial posted by @the_pantless_coder (this one https://www.codementor.io/tips/5748713276/how-to-upload-images-to-aws-s3-in-swift ) and I've decided to modify my existing method `imagePickerController`, so far it looks like this:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        imageView.image = image
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})

        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:CognitoRegionType,
            identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:CognitoRegionType, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        let ext = "png"
        let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("image", withExtension: ext)!

        let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
        uploadRequest.body = imageURL
        uploadRequest.key = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
        uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
        uploadRequest.contentType = "image/" + ext
    }
```

but I have a problem with this line:

```
let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("image", withExtension: ext)!
```

how can I get the imageURL when I only have a `imageView.image = image` here?

Comment: Maybe these links might help you, they have examples in swift. https://www.codementor.io/tips/5748713276/how-to-upload-images-to-aws-s3-in-swift      http://blog.jaarce.com/2015/03/uploading-image-to-s3-via-swift.html

Comment: can you provide your code so that I can help you on implement as you are asking is broad concept so I'll make the demo if you provide your code

Comment: @techloverr thanks, what I have so far is the code that I provided above in my original question, as for now I would like to have even a very simple plain application in swift that does this one simple thing - fetches the image from camera and uploads it to my s3 bucket, nothing more, could you help me with providing a simple code with an app built from scratch?

Comment: So please provide that code with all S3 keys then I'll update and send you

Comment: @techloverr I have the necessary keys stored in my `Constans.swift` file, I included them in the general question above, I didn't provide the real data of course since it's my personal bucket, just a general schema of how I store it in my application, I hope that's helpful

Comment: @the_pantless_coder thanks for that tutorial, I've decided to go with that, can you check my edit to the original question?

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have a bridging header in place in place where you can import the appropriate AWS headers. There is an example located [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Swift/S3TransferManagerSampleSwift/ObjectiveC-Bridging-Header.h) on GitHub.

Doing this should make the S3 methods available.

-Rohan

Comment: Thanks Rohan, I added the bridging header, but I still have no idea how should i even begin with adding the upload funcionality, I looked everywhere for any swift tutorial of aws (since I'm at a very very beginning of coding in swift) and also I noticed that other people have similar problems, thats the reason why I posted this question. I will start a bounty here as soon as it's possible, maybe some developer will be kind enough to leave us a more direct and strict answer with a specific code snippets :) thanks for your comment though!

Comment: The link in the answer is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Based on input from @the-pantless-coder, you can save the image into temporary file and delete the file once the upload is complete.

Try :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        let path = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingString("image.jpeg")

        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
            data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})

        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:CognitoRegionType,
            identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:CognitoRegionType, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        let ext = "jpeg"

        let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
        uploadRequest.body = path
        uploadRequest.key = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
        uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
        uploadRequest.contentType = "image/" + ext
    }
```

Comment: Ok, for the record, the code above works after chaning `uploadRequest.body = path` to `uploadRequest.body = NSURL(string: "file://"+path)`, the rest is great :) Then I'm following the example from the link provided by @the_pantless_coder and do `let s3URL = NSURL(string: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/\(S3BucketName)/\(uploadRequest.key!)")!
                print("Uploaded to:\n\(s3URL)")` But is it possible to show the user the image he chose? Currently I only print the URL of the image when the image is uploaded...

Comment: You can show the image to the user by getting `UIImage` from that file location. use `UIImage(contentsOfFile: <#T##String#>)`